# write a function of the disjunctive pattern bind the same variables

Tags: ocaml, coq

I have this type

```
Inductive coef :=
| Mycoef_ex2 : matrix -> coef
with matrix :=
| My_matrix : list (list coef) -> matrix.

Inductive my_type :=
| Mytype_ex1 : list my_type  -> my_type
| Mytype_int : Z -> my_type
| Mytype_coef : coef -> my_type.
```

In `Ocaml` I can write:

```
let test_mytype := function
| Mytype_ex1 [Mytype_coef (Mycoef_ex2 (My_matrix m)); Mytype_int i] :: ps -> ...
```

I want to use the argument `m` and `i` in the same function where my function needed both arguments.But In `Coq` I cannot do that for example if I write in `Coq`

```
Definition test_mytype (m: my_type) :=
 match m with
  | Mytype_ex1 (Mytype_coef (Mycoef_ex2 (My_matrix m)))
  | Mytype_int i :: ps => my_function m i
   ...
 end.
```

I got an error :

```
Toplevel input, characters 82-215:
Error: The components of this disjunctive pattern must bind the same variables.
```

If I write this function like below the `Coq` will accepted, but I cannot use both `m` and `i` as the same time

```
Definition test_mytype (m: my_type) :=
 match m with
  | Mytype_ex1 (Mytype_coef (Mycoef_ex2 (My_matrix m))) :: ps => ...
  | Mytype_ex1 (Mytype_int i) :: ps => ...
    ...
 end.
```

I also tried to use the matching for example:

```
Definition test_mytype (m1, m2: my_type) :=
 match m1, m2 with
  | Mytype_ex1 (Mytype_coef (Mycoef_ex2 (My_matrix m))) :: ps, 
  | Mytype_ex1 (Mytype_int i) :: ps => ...
    ...
 end.
```

But my problem is both `m` and `i` should belong to the same `m: my_type`.

Do you know how can I write the function `test_mytype` that can use both `m` and `i` as the same time in `Coq`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you do not have a good grasp of what *disjunctive patterns* are about.

### In OCaml

Let us say, for example, that I have, in OCaml, defined a type `either`:

```
type either = Left of int | Right of int
```

Hence, a value of type `either` is just an integer tagged with either `Left` or `Right`.

One obvious function that I can now write is `int_of_either`, which takes a value of type `either` as its argument and produces an integer as its result:

```
let int_of_either = function
  | Left x -> x
  | Right x -> x
```

Now, note that the cases for `Left` and `Right` have identical right-hand sides. In that case, disjunctive patterns allow me to render my function just a bit more concise by having the two arms of the pattern match share a single right-hand side:

```
let int_of_either = function
  | Left x
  | Right x -> x
```

Of course, this only works out if the variable `x` is bound in both patterns. (Moreover, the bindings should be consistent in the sense that they should agree on the type of `x`. Here, they do as both cases bind `x` to a value of type `int`.)

That is, if I write, for instance

```
let int_of_either = function
  | Left x
  | Right y -> y
```

the compiler will reject my program and complain about `y` not occurring in the case for `Left`:

> Error: Variable y must occur on both sides of this | pattern

## In Coq

In a similar manner, if, in Coq, I define a type `either`

```
Inductive either :=
  | Left : Z -> either
  | Right : Z -> either.
```

and a function `int_of_either`

```
Definition int_of_either (e : either) : Z :=
  match e with
  | Left x => x
  | Right x => x
  end.
```

then I can use a disjunctive pattern to rewrite `int_of_either` into

```
Definition int_of_either (e : either) : Z :=
  match e with
  | Left x
  | Right x => x
  end.
```

However, if I write

```
Definition int_of_either (e : either) : Z :=
  match e with
  | Left x
  | Right y => y
  end.
```

the compiler complains with

> Error: The components of this disjunctive pattern must bind the same variables.

which is exactly the error you are getting.

---

In conclusion, I recommend forgetting about disjunctive patterns for now and first try to get your function defined with a dedicated right-hand side for each arm of your pattern match and only then consider whether your function can be written in a slightly more compact form.

Answer (score 2):

```
 match m with
  | Mytype_ex1 (Mytype_coef (Mycoef_ex2 (My_matrix m)))
  | Mytype_int i :: ps
     => my_function m i
```

Is wrong and cannot work. Not only the first matches a `my_type` and
the second a `my_type list`, but in a disjunctive pattern (or-pattern)
both sides must capture the same variable: it doesn't make sense to
defined `m` in a case, `i` in the other, and to expect both to be
defined in a branch.

So I don't know what you're trying to do, but Coq and OCaml has the
same limitations here, and there should not be a difference.